# domready is not defined

Tags: 8, javascript

I'm building my own theme to be used with Angular 4 and can't tell where/why Drupal is deciding to import jQuery.

Here's the code for my theme, loosely based off [this Angular 1 theme](https://github.com/agungsuyono/drupal_ng):

**ng.info.yml**

```
name: ng
type: theme
libraries:
  - ng/base
description: 'An theme that makes Angular do all the work'
core: 8.x
```

**ng.libraries.yml**

```
base:
  version: 8.x
  js:
    js/inline.bundle.js: {}
    js/polyfills.bundle.js: {}
    js/styles.bundle.js: {}
    js/vendor.bundle.js: {}
    js/main.bundle.js: {}
```

**ng.module**

```
<?php
function ng_theme() {
  return array(
    'ng_view' => array(
      'template' => 'view',
      'variables' => array('title' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}
```

**ng.routing.yml**

```
ng.view:
  path: 'ng'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Drupal Angular'
    _controller: '\Drupal\ng\Controller\DrupalNgController::viewDrupalNg'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**src/Controller/DrupalNgController**

```
namespace Drupal\ng\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
class DrupalNgController extends ControllerBase {
  public function viewDrupalNg() {
    $build['myelement'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'ng_view',
    );
    $build['myelement']['#attached']['library'][] = 'ng/inline.bundle';
    $build['myelement']['#attached']['library'][] = 'ng/polyfills.bundle';
    $build['myelement']['#attached']['library'][] = 'ng/styles.bundle';
    $build['myelement']['#attached']['library'][] = 'ng/vendor.bundle';
    $build['myelement']['#attached']['library'][] = 'ng/main.bundle';
    return $build;
  }
}
```

**templates/view.html.twig**

```
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
  <head>
    <title>Angular app</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
    <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="YES" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's probably listed as a dependency of another library that's being included in the page. Dependencies are automatically included with their dependants

Comment: A contributed module could be doing it too.

Comment: @Clive another JS library or Drupal? I'm not using it with any of my JavaScript

Comment: @Kevin looking through some of the default themes, I don't see them including jQuery, and so far, I haven't added anything outside of the core modules. Is jQuery a requirement for Drupal?

Comment: Well, something must be including it. It won't load unless explicitly asked for. Are you looking at the site anonymously?

Comment: I meant another Drupal library (like the one you've defined in your .libraries.yml but defined by another module/theme). Pages are complex beasts, any part of the build can request that any library is added, and any library can depend on any number of other libraries. Something your page depends on itself depends on jQuery, or depends on something that depends on jquery, and so on. I don't know of an easy way to identify what's coming from where given just the markup

Answer (score 0):

Given you didn't install any contrib modules nor themes, dozens of Drupal core modules requires Jquery to function. You'll have to check what modules lists JQuery as a dependency.
Search in `core/modules` and `core/themes` directories for `core/jquery` and you'll find out what module/theme is adding it and disable it.

For example "contextual" module needs it.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `core/domready` library to dependencies part of your theme libraries file:
my_theme.libraries.yml

```
...
script:
  ...
  dependencies:
     - core/jquery
     - core/jquery.once
     - core/drupal
     - core/domready
```